# Does the sample size calculation depend on the type of distribution?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, sample-size

For example, will the minimum sample size for a 95% confidence interval and 2% margin of error be different for a normal, binomial, Poisson, Geometric, Weibul, etc distribution?

Comment: The confidence interval of what parameter?

Comment: When estimating a population mean, CIs may be similar (especially for normal, binomial, Poisson) for large sample sizes (on account of the Central LImit Theorem). But for small sample sizes, the nature of the population distribution needs to be taken into account.